# Weak (operator) null sequence is bounded and pointwise convergent to zero

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, topological-vector-spaces

I was reading Diestel book (Absolutely Summing Operators) and it says:

"(...) let $(f_n)$ be any weak null sequence in $\mathcal{C}(K)$. Then $(f_n)$ is bounded and converges pointwise to zero."

I was trying to check this assertion but I am not convinced with my proof. My idea is based in the weak operator compactness of closed bounded sets which can be used to prove that the convergence is uniform in the functionals. Then, taking the supremum, the pointwise convergence follows. Is that correct?

Comment: Pointwise evaluation is a continuous linear functional; hence the pointwise convergence. Any weakly convergent sequence is norm  bounded; this follows from the Uniform Boundedness Principle.

Comment: I may be misinterpreting you, but in need not be the case that $(f_n)$ converges to $0$ uniformly.

Comment: David, I agree with you that the boundedness follows from Uniform Boundedness Principle.
In fact, I think there is a misinterpreting. The supremum I was talking about was over the norm-one functional (the point is fixed). A corollary of Hahn-Banach say this supremum coincides with the norm (in the fixed point). Hence, in fact it does not converges to 0 uniformly.